# MVC Return List of Columns Other Than Full Model

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I have a Model created with a table called "Customers".

It contains the following fields:

- CustomerProfileID
- CustomerName
- BirthDate
- Address1
- City
- State
- Zip
- CreatedOn
- CreatedBy

I did a "Function Import" of a Stored Procedure (CustomerProfiles_Search) that Searches the table.  (I cannot post the Sproc due to sensitive information).  The "Returns a Collection Of" is set to "Entities: CustomerProfile". It returns the following:

- CustomerName
- BirthDate
- Address1

**Now here is where I get confused.**  I have my Controller that is passing in the fields to search by and then passes it into my "Gateway" which returns a list.

**My Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetRowCount(string CustomerName, string BirthDate, string Address1, string City, string State, string Zip)
{
    List<CustomerProfile> searchResults = CustomerProfileGateway.Search(CustomerName, BirthDate, Address1, City, State, Zip);

    int count = searchResults.Count();
    string rowCount = count.ToString();

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return Content(rowCount);
    else
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "OneView");
}
```

... Inside my **CustomerProfileGateway.cs** file:

```
public static List<CustomerProfile> Search(string CustomerName, string BirthDate, string Address1, string City, string State, int Zip)
{
    using (ModelEntities context = new ModelEntities())
    {
        return context.CustomerProfiles_Search(CustomerName, BirthDate, Address1, City, State, Zip).ToList();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to output the results to a List, I get an error when I do:

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'SVPModel.CustomerProfile'. A member of the type, 'CustomerProfileID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

I think I need to create a Model of what is returned.

**I created the following:**

```
namespace Project.ABC.Objects
{
    class SearchModel
    {
            public class SearchResults
            {
                public string CustomerName { get; set; }
                public string BirthDate { get; set; }
                public string Address1 { get; set; }
            }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to do this?  Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong here.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your sproc is not returning all the columns you are requiring by saying that it should map to a `CustomerProfile`.

When it tries to read the properties from the `DataReader`, it can't find a column called `CustomerProfileID`, hence the message:

> A member of the type, 'CustomerProfileID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Your `SearchResults` looks good. You just have to set "Returns a Collection Of" to "Entities: SearchResults"

Comment: That's what I tried to do, @Pedro.  When I look at the dropdown menu of "Entities", my "SearchResults" do not show up in there.  How do I make this happen?  My SearchModel is in my Objects folder that also has the main model named SVPModel.edmx.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Honestly, I never used the UI for that. But shouldn't your `SearchResults` inherit from `EntityObject`? Try this: comment your `SearchResults` and create a new entity in the edmx designer with the 3 properties you need. It should do it I guess, but again, I'm not an expert on this...